# Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/dev: Invalid argument in all my Ubuntu servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Since last day, suddenly some of my services stopped (different services accross different servers) with the following error (the error is the same among all):

```
Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/dev: Invalid argument
Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/sbin/PACKAGE: Invalid argument
```

My current workaround to make services `start` is:

```
systemctl edit THAT_SERVICE
```

Add the following lines:

```
[Service]
PrivateDevices=yes
```

Then:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart THAT_SERVICE
```

I googled a lot but found nothing for this issue.